# Local Image object not getting initialized properly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am facing an issue where local object in For loop in not getting initialized for every iteration in Javascript.

Below code works fine:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2)
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

    setMarkers(map, beaches);
}

var beaches = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png']
];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var beach = locations[i];

        var image = {
            url: beach[4],
            size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
        };

        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title: beach[0],
            zIndex: beach[3]
        });
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)
```

However, if my first array becomes like this, all the flags stops displaying.:

```
['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4, ''];
```

Why Map Marker is not getting initialized every time? Is there something in Google Maps which I am missing here?

JSFiddle link for the sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/anujagg/Lrkvu4mu/25/

Thanks.

Comment: I can't believe that someone down-voted this question. I struggled for 2 hrs to find out something else is messing up my code and wanted to understand why it is not working as expected. The same piece of code would have worked fine in C/C++/Java. I created a JSFiddle to explain this out properly and getting comment that question is unclear. Looks like there is something regarding SO which I am not yet able to fig out. On one hand, I see so many useless homework type questions here which no one downvotes where questions like this get beaten up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google.maps.Icon is not valid with a url of ''.

```
var image = {
        url: beach[4],
        size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
    };
```

There is a javascript error generated in that case:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dx' of undefined

Change the code to pass in a null for image in that case:

```
if (beach[4] != '') {
  var image = {
      url: beach[4],
      size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
  };
} else {
  var image = null;
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrkvu4mu/26/)

code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2)
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  setMarkers(map, beaches);
}

var beaches = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4, ''],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1, 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png']
];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var beach = locations[i];
    if (beach[4] != '') {
      var image = {
        url: beach[4],
        size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
      };
    } else {
      var image = null;
    }

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      title: beach[0],
      zIndex: beach[3]
    });
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
      html,
      body,
      #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this partially answers my problem although the same is not mentioned in Google docs (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) and some people feel it is stupid to clarify undocumented things. However, If URL is not valid, then I can understand marker is not getting displayed properly. But for the next iteration, when everything is fine, why a new Marker is not getting created with a new URL? Are local variables not created the same way in JS as they are in C++ or Java?

Comment: javascript errors cause the processing of the loop to abort, so it never even tries to process the remaining "good" markers.

Comment: Thanks, it now helps. Can some one help me with why people downvoted this question? I am yet to find out the reason for that.